# How to compile pyfftw with buildozer?

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer, pyfftw

I am trying to build an Android app using `buildozer`. The source code is using `pyfftw` which is not included in the recipes. Therefore, the library is downloaded with pip.

I am running the code in Ubuntu 16.04 and using Python 3.6

I compiled with different arch armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, but still the app crashes.

I also tried to write my own recipe, but it does not seem to make a difference. Not sure if the recipe is correct, though.

When trying with `arm64-v8a`. I get this error:

`ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.opencvtest/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/pyfftw/pyfftw.so" has unexpected e_machine: 62 (EM_X86_64)`

Any idea about this?

Comment: I think this may indicate that pyfftw is compiled for the wrong architecture. It probably needs a python-for-android build recipe to compile properly.

Comment: pyfftw will probably compile for ARM, but is a work in progress to check everything properly.